# Which nmap command for ip addresses

Tags: ip, nmap

Is there a way to tell nmap to generate IP addresses with `-sL` command, but only output addresses ending in ".255"?
I have done some Googling but I have gotten nothing; or is there another program that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to specify IP addresses to Nmap. You probably want to specify octet ranges like this:

```
nmap -sL -n 192.168.0-255.255
```

This will output all 256 addresses that are like "192.168.1.255" or "192.168.13.255". You can replace any octet with a range like this.